# headerFilterParams without editor

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, tabulator

I would like to enable users to filter for predefined keywords (`headerFilterParams`) with `headerFilter`. However, the `headerFilter` [example on the Tabulator website](http://tabulator.info/examples/4.5#filter-header) also activates a cell editor.

```
 {title:"Gender", field:"gender", editor:"select", editorParams:{values:{"male":"Male", "female":"Female"}}, headerFilter:true, headerFilterParams:{values:{"male":"Male", "female":"Female", "":""}}},
```

If I remove the cell editor with `editor:"select", editorParams:{values:{"male":"Male", "female":"Female"}},`, the keywords in the column header disappear. How can I use `headerFilter` with `headerFilterParams` without activating the editor?
For now, I passed on empty parameters but that's not really a nice solution because cells still get a blue cell border when selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want an editor in the column don't define the ***editor*** property in the column definition.

Setting the ***headerFilter*** property to true causes it to use the same value as the editor property, so in this instance just set the ***headerFilter*** property to "select"

```
{title:"Gender", field:"gender", headerFilter:"select", headerFilterParams:{values:{"male":"Male", "female":"Female", "":""}}},
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! That doesn't work for me. If I remove `editor:"select",` or use `editor:"",` the dropdown menu with `headerFilterParams:{...}` is replaced with a _normal_ search field.

Comment: You need to set the headerFilter property to "select", setting it to true tells it to use the editor

Comment: Great! i have edited my original answer to make that clearer